# How can I use lockbox gem with ransack gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

Using Lockbox gem I encrypted my email column in the database but now I'm facing error when trying to use `<%= f.search_field :email_cont %>`. Please suggest me how can I handle it.

Error:

```
undefined method `email_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use Ransack with Lockbox, since data encrypted at the application-level isn't searchable on the database-level / with SQL.

If Ransack could search arrays in addition to database models, this would be possible (but inefficient) since records could be loaded and decrypted, but looking through the Ransack code, it's not supported as of August 2020.